# Mantel test or/and correlation test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

Do you know the difference between the Mantel test and a Pearson correlation test? I know that in the Mantel test we look for a correlation between two matrices and in a Pearson test, a correlation between two dataframes.

Thus, which method of correlation is used in the Mantel test?

For example:

```
#       x        y

#A-B    12      0.12
#A-C    5       0.45
#A-D    8       0.69
#A-E    10      0.1
#B-C    4       0.17
#B-D    1       0.3
#C-D    7       0.36
```

A,B,C,D,E represent one site. "x" is the genetic distance between sites (e.g. A-B, A-C, A-D ...) and "y" is the geographical distance between sites.

I want apply a Mantel test between those two columns. Is this the same as applying a Pearson correlation test between the two columns?

Answer (score 3):

First, let's clear up some terminology: the term "data frame" doesn't refer to anything mathematical. It's a data structure in R and Pandas for working with tabular data. For *statistical* questions, I think it's better to think of data frames and matrices as interchangeable.

Second, Pearson correlation is defined on *vectors*. You're probably thinking of a correlation *matrix*, which is a matrix of pairwise correlations between more than two vectors, such as the vectors representing different variables in a tabular data set (which you could in turn represent in R as a data frame). The Pearson correlation *test* is likewise defined on vectors.

Meanwhile the Mantel test is defined on true matrices. However it is actually intended for use specifically on distance matrices, which are derived from data vectors. So both the Pearson correlation test and Mantel test can be used to test relationships between vectors. The difference lies in the question that each test is designed to answer. The Pearson correlation test answers something like the question

> When $X$ goes up, does $Y$ also go up? When $X$ goes down, does $Y$ also go down?

while the Mantel test answers something like the question

> When any two $X$ observations are similar, are the corresponding $Y$ observations also similar? When any two $X$ observations are dissimilar, are the corresponding $Y$ observations also dissimilar?

There's a very nice explanation of Mantel's test [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180612162253/https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/files/scicomp/doc/SpatialEcologyMantelTest.pdf).

To answer the second part of your question: Pearson's correlation coefficient is used "under the hood" in both tests. It's just used differently.

Comment: Nice corrections! I think you answered to my question. But i want to specify the situation that I 'm facing. I have to do a Mantel test between a genetic distance matrix and a geographical distance matrix. I discovered that whther I use all the values of the matrices, I gonna obtain a bias in the results. Thus, the right thing to do is to select the sites that are geographical close according to some criteria.... In this way I obtained two vectors: one with genetic distance between those sites and another with the geographic distance among them. Can I use a Pearson correlation test?

Comment: @user29859 I'm not sure I understand your technique. What does each element of each vector correspond to?

Comment: I have two vectors (i.e. two columns of values). One column correspond to  the genetic distance between two geographical sites. The other column corresponds to the respective geographical distance between the two sites. My ain is to  do the Mantel test between those two columns.

Comment: @CafféSospeso so you have several observations at each site? Would you mind adding a "mock up" of the data to your post?

Comment: I added a mock up.

Comment: @CafféSospeso and what do you mean that you "obtained a bias?"

Comment: A recent article showed that the isolation by distance (or correlation between geographic and genetic distances) could be biased if in the Mantel test we consider all the sites, instead of use ONLY the sites that are distant to a maximum distance. Such distance could be computed by some other analyses.

Comment: @CafféSospeso I'm not sure how you'd apply the Mantel test with a "partial" matrix. Keep in mind that the Mantel test is really just a permutation test for the correlation between two matrices in which the rows and columns are randomly shuffled. You might be able just performing a permutation test of the correlation between those two vectors you have. I suspect that randomly shuffling rows and columns is equivalent to randomly shuffling elements, but I don't have a proof for you

Comment: This is what I thought. For this reason I was looking for the correlation test formule used in the Mantel test for applying that to my vectors. My hypothesis was that, actually, corresponded to Pearson correlation test and, thus, to use the latter. What do you think?

Comment: By the way, your mantel explanation link is very helpful, but has been reprinted from D.L. Urban without proper citation/acknowledgment. For a PDF version that hasn't been copied and stripped of the author's name, see [here](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/files/scicomp/doc/SpatialEcologyMantelTest.pdf)